# Change list to string

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to change this list to string, but I do not know how to make the first and last to be |- and -| respectively. Logically thinking, S.join will join the list together but will not change before **0** and after **9**, so any advice to how I can change them would be great.

```
index = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

newindex = "-|-".join(index)

>>>> 0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|-9
```

My expected output is:

```
|-0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|-9-|
```

Comment: What is your expected output? You need to provide [MCVE].

Comment: Does `''.join(index).replace('', '|-')` provide the required output?

Comment: @JonClements No, the one I have above `"|-".join(index)` is closer than yours.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Apologies buddy. Thought my explanation was sufficient. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Why not `newindex = "|-" + "-|-".join(index) + "-|"`?

Comment: That solved it for me. I knew the answer would be simple. Thanks!! Didn't think of that as I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting

```
"|-{}-|".format("-|-".join(index))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compile the list into a string with little to no effort with this package. Firstly do `pip install -U cool-utils` and then do the following code:

```py
import cool_utils

index = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
string = cool_utils.Compile.string(startwith="|-", endwith="-|", joints="-|-")
print(string)
>> |-0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|-9-|
```